# How do I output multiple different values of user input in Java?

Tags: java, loops, input, do-while

I would like this program below to capture user input (first product name, then costs), and then output to the console, and ask the user if they would like anything else, and if they do, it will do it again and output the next product and costs.

If the user replies with no, then I want it to output a list of the items by number and name, and then the total costs of how every many items were requested, and then a total overall cost.

Here is my code so far; I want to understand how to get the total overall costs and list each item. I feel like I am very close.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /////////Initialize everything here/////////
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String nameProd;
    String response;
    int items = 0;
    int costMat;
    int hoursReq;
    int payPerHr = 15; //cost per hour for only one employee, who is also the owner (me)
    double shipping = 13.25; //shipping cost remains constant even with multiple items
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    System.out.println("================================="
        + "\nWelcome to Ryan's Computer Store!"
        + "\n=================================");

    do{
        items++;
            //////////////////////////////////////////    
            System.out.print("Enter product name: ");
                nameProd = keyboard.next();
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    System.out.print("Enter cost of materials: $");
                        costMat = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("In hours, how soon would you prefer that this order is completed?: ");
                        hoursReq = keyboard.nextInt();
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        System.out.println("====================================================================" 
                            + "\n============================" 
                            + "\n>>>>>>Rundown of costs<<<<<<" 
                            + "\nItem #: " + items
                            + "\nItem Name: " + nameProd 
                            + "\nCost of Materials: $" + costMat 
                            + "\n===>Hours spent creating the product: " + hoursReq + " hours" 
                            + "\n===>Employee Pay Per Hour: $" + payPerHr);
                        int priceMarkup = hoursReq*payPerHr;
                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            System.out.println("Price of product after markup: $" 
                                + (priceMarkup+costMat));
                                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                System.out.println("===>Shipping Fee: $" + shipping);
                                    //////////////////////////////////////////////
                                    int costBeforeShipping = priceMarkup+costMat;
                                    double totAmt = shipping+costBeforeShipping;
                                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        System.out.println("Amount to be charged for item #" + items + " (" + nameProd + ")" + ": $" + totAmt
                                            + "\n============================");
                                                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                System.out.print("========================================================" 
                                                    + "\nIs there anything else that you would like to order?: ");
                                                    response = keyboard.next();
                                                    }
    while
        (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    System.out.println(">>>>>========================================================<<<<<\nTOTAL AMOUNT TO BE CHARGED FOR " + items + " ITEMS: " + "\nShipping (flat fee): " + shipping + "\nSum of Items: ");
}}
```

Comment: Investigate collections.  Everything that you want multiple copies of can go in a collection (array, list, set etc), and then you can access the collection's elements through an iterator/enumerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a list to hold item names and one temporary variable to hold sum of prices. I think below code will help you.

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String nameProd;
        String response;
        int items = 0;
        int costMat;
        int hoursReq;
        int payPerHr = 15; //cost per hour for only one employee, who is also the owner (me)
        double shipping = 13.25; //shipping cost remains constant even with multiple items
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        List<String> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
        double totalPrice=0;


        System.out.println("================================="
            + "\nWelcome to Ryan's Computer Store!"
            + "\n=================================");

        do{
            items++;
                //////////////////////////////////////////    
                System.out.print("Enter product name: ");
                    nameProd = keyboard.next();
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        System.out.print("Enter cost of materials: $");
                            costMat = keyboard.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("In hours, how soon would you prefer that this order is completed?: ");
                            hoursReq = keyboard.nextInt();
                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            System.out.println("====================================================================" 
                                + "\n============================" 
                                + "\n>>>>>>Rundown of costs<<<<<<" 
                                + "\nItem #: " + items
                                + "\nItem Name: " + nameProd 
                                + "\nCost of Materials: $" + costMat 
                                + "\n===>Hours spent creating the product: " + hoursReq + " hours" 
                                + "\n===>Employee Pay Per Hour: $" + payPerHr);

                            orderItems.add(nameProd);


                            int priceMarkup = hoursReq*payPerHr;
                                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                System.out.println("Price of product after markup: $" 
                                    + (priceMarkup+costMat));
                                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                    System.out.println("===>Shipping Fee: $" + shipping);
                                        //////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        int costBeforeShipping = priceMarkup+costMat;
                                        double totAmt = shipping+costBeforeShipping;
                                        totalPrice+=totAmt;
                                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                            System.out.println("Amount to be charged for item #" + items + " (" + nameProd + ")" + ": $" + totAmt
                                                + "\n============================");
                                                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                    System.out.print("========================================================" 
                                                        + "\nIs there anything else that you would like to order?: ");
                                                        response = keyboard.next();
                                                        }
        while
            (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        System.out.println(">>>>>========================================================<<<<<\nTOTAL AMOUNT TO BE CHARGED FOR  ITEMS: " + orderItems +  "\nShipping (flat fee): " + shipping + "\nSum of Items: "+totalPrice);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, is there a way that I can add to the output a breakdown of cost per item? So for example, for sum of items, it would show what the total cost is for item 1 upward, then a grand total.

Comment: @Ryan of course, YES. You can make use of a new list like orderItems  to hold prices.